# change product id to product name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

```
{
            "_id": "639c6ce4f1457fbbcc88a28e",
            "name": "Laptop Lenovo Slim 1",
            "img": "https://d3o2e4jr3mxnm3.cloudfront.net/Mens-Jake-Guitar-Vintage-Crusher-Tee_68382_1_lg.png",
            "price": 100000,
            "desc": "Proident culpa commodo ipsum qui sint amet. Elit id elit fugiat qui excepteur veniam id consequat reprehenderit Lorem. Est cupidatat voluptate enim fugiat irure aute mollit nulla culpa occaecat eiusmod do sint.",
            "category": [
                "Laptop"
            ],
            "stock": 10,
            "weight": 3000,
            "ratings": 5,
            "allReviews": 12,
            "reviews": []
        }
```

I have product data in mongodb, like this

when I want to get the product detail, it can be retrieved by defining product id in url, something like this

{{URL}}/api/product/639c6ce4f1457fbbcc88a28e,

But if I want to get product detail by product's name, should I retrieve it like this:

{{URL}}/api/product/laptop-lenovo-slim-1,

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you need to find and project the name [see this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/findOne/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating new product add one more field you can called it (slug), this will be you URL-friendly title you can convert your title to a slug using something like this

```
function generateSlug(title) {
  return title.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/g, '').trim('-');
}

const title = 'My Awesome Title';
const slug = generateSlug(title); // 'my-awesome-title'
```

Then you can simply query the database for the slug, this is the most hassle free way of doing it.